# UIButton dashed underline in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

Normal underline works but dotted undeline doesn't seems to work?

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
btn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 10, 300, 300);
NSMutableAttributedString *titleString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Durga Vundavalli"];

// making text property to underline text-
[titleString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:NSMakeRange(0, [titleString length])];

// using text on button
[btn setAttributedTitle: titleString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

The following was the enum from documentation:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, NSUnderlineStyle) {
    NSUnderlineStyleNone                                = 0x00,
    NSUnderlineStyleSingle                              = 0x01,
    NSUnderlineStyleThick NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0)    = 0x02,
    NSUnderlineStyleDouble NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0)   = 0x09,

    NSUnderlinePatternSolid NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0)      = 0x0000,
    NSUnderlinePatternDot NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0)        = 0x0100,
    NSUnderlinePatternDash NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0)       = 0x0200,
    NSUnderlinePatternDashDot NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0)    = 0x0300,
    NSUnderlinePatternDashDotDot NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0) = 0x0400,

    NSUnderlineByWord NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0) = 0x8000
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't put only `NSUnderlinePatternDot`. What if you want 2 lines of dots? You have to use a `Pattern` and a `Style`.

```
[titleString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:(NSUnderlinePatternDot|NSUnderlineStyleSingle)] range:NSMakeRange(0, [titleString length])];
```

You have to use a mask, as said by the doc:

> Discussion 
>   The style, pattern, and optionally by-word mask are OR'd
>   together to produce the value for `NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName` and
>   `NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName`.